# Open URL on SMS receive - Android ap

Tags: sms-gateway

Can someone please help me how to make this app for android

1. i send SMS to android with text "message content"
2. ap that works in background sends post request opening predefined URL with SMS parameters ex http://www.website.com/send.php?number=45665445877&message=message content&time=10:10:10&date=10.10.2011.

in this way i could communicate with my ap on web server

Thank you!

Comment: I'm also looking for this - there's a thing called Twilio, it does just that, but it's kind of expensive. And it's a web service - not an android app.